# Реализация рассылки PushUp уведомлений для Android и iOS на PHP

Tags: php, android, ios, pushup

Добрый день, уважаемые форумчане.

Столкнулся с необходимостью рассылки PushUp уведомлений конкретным пользователям из БД. 
До этого делал только массовые рассылки всем пользователям с установленным ПО, а вот выборочно нет. Поэтому прошу Вашего совета и рекомендация, как это реализовать.

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? В APNS/GCM нет возможности послать сообщение всем пользователям. Сообщение всем - это, условно, посылка сообщения каждому по очереди. То есть проблем здесь не может возникнуть в принципе

Comment: Как идентифицировать каждого пользователя конкретно?

Comment: У вас же есть точки для регистрации устройств. Вот там вместе с reg id устройства передавайте и ID юзера

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте!

Чтобы иметь возможность делать рассылку Push сообщений пользователям, необходимо "собрать" токены устройств и сохранить их в базу. Вместе с токеном, в зависимости от задач, можно сохранить дополнительную информацию о пользователе, например, идентификатор устройства (UDID, vendorId и др), город, соц. профиль под которым он был авторизован в вашем приложении и любую другую информацию.

Для того, чтобы разослать сообщения пользователям из Москвы, сначала нужно будет сделать выборку:

```
SELECT token FROM devices WHERE location = 'Moscow'
```

Затем, имея Push-сертификат и используя например [ApnsPHP](https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP), выполнить перебор массива $tokens:

```
for ($tokens as $token) {
    $push = new ApnsPHP_Push(
        ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION,
        'server_certificates_bundle_prod.pem');

    $push->setRootCertificationAuthority('entrust_root_certification_authority.pem');
    $push->connect();
    $message = new ApnsPHP_Message($token);
    $message->setBadge(3);
    $message->setText('Привет, житель Москвы!');
    $push->add($message);
    $push->send();
    $push->disconnect();
}
```